# Why am I getting this error when my entire dataframe is composed of numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, scaling

I am trying to scale my parameters as a part of data-preprocessing for some basic machine learning implementation. My dataset is composed entirely of numbers after  I factorised the columns.I also removed all the NAs.
The typeof function also proves the dataset is converted into numerics and sum(is.na) justifies the presence of no NA-

```
lapply(training_set, typeof)
$Country
[1] "integer"

$Age
[1] "double"

$Salary
[1] "double"

$Purchased
[1] "integer" 

sum(is.na(training_set))
[1] 0
```

But on scaling my data-

```
train=scale(training_set)
```

I get this

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

The data is-

```
training_set
   Country      Age   Salary Purchased
1        1 44.00000 72000.00         1
2        3 27.00000 48000.00         1
3        3 30.00000 54000.00         0
4        2 38.00000 61000.00         0
5        3 40.00000 63777.78         1
7        2 38.77778 52000.00         0
8        3 48.00000 79000.00         0
10       2 37.00000 67000.00         1
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Comment: it is working for me.  May be you have `factor` class.  Please test `sapply(training_set, class)` insteead of `typeof`

Comment: FYI: `typeof(factor(letters))` returns `"integer"`, yet `scale(factor(letters))` still fails. It might be more informative for you to run `lapply(training_set, class)` instead of `typeof`. (My guess is that either or both of `Country` and `Purchased` are really factors.)

Comment: I don't get that error with the data you provided

Comment: B_man, your sample here is a good example of an ambiguous data sample, and I think it does a good job demonstrating the difference between what an object ***is*** and how an object is stored internally. For example, if you look at `head(iris)`, the last column looks like strings but is stored internally as integers (with levels). Two unambiguous ways to show data are with `str(training_set)` or `dput(head(training_set))`, where the latter is better for a few reasons (not least of which is that it is far easier for us to test and use, whereas `str` takes a lot of work.)